# Java Error: Unreported exception?

Tags: java, generics, custom-exceptions

I've got the following method:

```
public T peek() throws StackEmptyException {
    Node<T> tracker = head; 
    while(tracker.getNext() != null) {
        tracker = tracker.getNext(); 
    }
    return tracker.getItem(); 
}
```

The problem is that when I try to do something like

```
int firstOne = stack.peek();
```

I get an `unreported exception StackEmptyException` and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong at this point. The `StackEmptyException` has been made in a separate class. Am I suppose to have this class extend that new exception class I made? So confused. Thoughts guys?

Comment: This has nothing to do with generics - it's just normal checked exceptions. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Yeah, so why exactly is it reporting that when I compile it?

Comment: Because you have extended `Exception`, as such your exception is a checked exception. This means code using your method should catch it, or the method in which `.peek()` is used should `throws` it as well.

Comment: Because it's a checked exception, and you're calling it from a method which neither catches it nor declares that it throws it. Please read the tutorial.

Comment: @fge but the peek() method does have a "throws" clause. Does that not satisfy the condition? Or do I need to use try/catch statements when invoking the stack.peek ?

Comment: No, that does not satisfy the condition for methods that _call_ this method. Such methods should try/catch or rethrow it (your choice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked exceptions (ie, a class which extends `Exception` but not `RuntimeException` or `Error`) thrown by a method should be handled by this method's caller, recursively so.

Here you have `.peek()` which throws, say, exception class `E` (bad name, but this is for illustration). You must do one of the following in a `foo()` method which calls `.peek()`:

- `catch` it, or
- throw it again.

That is, either:

```
// catch
void foo()
{
    try {
        peek();
    } catch (E e) {
       // something
    }
}
```

or:

```
// throw
void foo() throws E
{
    peek();
}
```

You could even rethrow it:

```
// catch then rethrow
void foo() throws E
{
    try {
        peek();
    } catch (E e) {
        // something, then
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `StackEmptyException` is an *checked exception* (which you shouldn't do in first place), you should handle that exception when invoking the `peek()` method. The rule is, either you should handle the exception or declare it to be thrown.

However, I would take a step back and change `StackEmptyException` to an *Unchecked Exception*. Then you wouldn't need to handle it or declare it as thrown.

Comment: " (which you shouldn't do in first place)" <-- why?

Comment: This is an assignment, so I have no choice, but to do it the way they want me to.

Comment: So are you saying that I would have to use try/catch when declaring int firstOne = stack.peek(); ?

Comment: @Vimzy Yes. Either that, or declare it in `throws` clause of method.

Comment: @RohitJain But that's exactly what I've done. If you look at my method code above, I add the "throws" clause in the method declaration. I'm not understanding. I have to do that, and the try/catch?

Comment: @Vimzy Ok, how about showing us the method where you're invoking the `peek()` method? Post the actual code you've.